# Does every connected metrizable space have uncountably many distinct open sets, each of which generating a connected subspace?

Tags: general-topology

I would suspect that the answer is "yes". Of course any connected metrizable space is uncountable. And any such space has uncountably many open sets: For one can easily show by an inductive argument that any such space has a countably infinite, pairwise disjoint sequence of open sets.  Moreover, the space obviously has infinitely many spheres and each sphere is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Any singleton space is metrizable and connected, but only has one element.

Comment: To Ittay: I mean any connected metrizable space with more than one element.

Comment: To David Mitra: Yes---sorry